# Links inside Bootstrap column become unclickable on window resize

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have the following code in my HTML page. The links work fine when the browser window is maximized however, when I test the same on a mobile browser, the links become unclickable.

```
<div class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-2 col-xs-5">
    <label>Legal</label><br>
    <a href="./termsofuse.html">Terms of Use</a><br>
    <a href="./privacypolicy.html">Privacy Policy</a><br>
    <a href="#FAQ">FAQs</a><br>
</div>
```

If I remove the bootstrap column classes from the DIV, the links again become clickable even on xs-screen. So I am sure that this is some issue with BS. Are there any workarounds for this?

Comment: works fine [here](http://jsfiddle.net/nx8w5zmv/). reproduce the issue in fiddle.

Comment: @JSantosh: I have reproduced the issue in fiddle here http://jsfiddle.net/akashsinghal/93b1x26a/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your disclaimer CSS is mixed in with the other two columns in the same row and overlapping the links.
(see how much room your disclaimer takes here: http://jsfiddle.net/93b1x26a/2/)

You need to add your disclaimer into a separate row.  Something along the lines of: (now, I do not know how you want the disclaimer bit to behave, so I just gave you this code as a sample working alternative) -

See [updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/93b1x26a/3/):

```
<div class="myfooter" id="footer">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-2 col-xs-5">
                <label>Legal</label>
                <!-- contents of first col -->
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-2 col-xs-7">
                <label>More</label>
                <!-- contents of second col -->
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- separate row for disclaimer -->
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-8" id="disclaimer">
                <label>Disclaimer</label>
                <br>
                <p>Placeholder text</br>
                    <p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: you are too fast :) +1

Comment: @JSantosh hahaha! thx... on a hunch, I tried to see if that was the issue.  It's overlapping... I just don't know how the OP wants to layout the three divs...

Comment: OP forgot to add medium ,small an extra small to disclaimer div, but OP added them to 1st 2 divs.

Comment: Thanks!! I am very new to front-end development and hence the issue...really thank you both for the prompt response.

Comment: @JohnLocke I am glad I could help.  Depending on how you want your `#disclaimer` div to behave, you may find that @JSantosh 's answer will suit you better.

Comment: @ochi : adding col-*-* to the #disclaimer itself worked for both enabling the links and displaying the #disclaimer properly.

Comment: @JSantosh : Thanks for the tip on correcting the tags. I have been a bit careless about tags as browser typically corrects some of these typos..but will be very careful about it from now onwards.

Comment: Perfect!, then it sounds like you should pick @JSantosh's answer and upvote mine (as you found it useful)

Answer (score 2):

@ochi pointed out the issue . the `#disclaimer` div is overlapping on others because you gave `col-xs=*,col-sm-*,col-md-*` to other divs but forgot to give the same to this disclaimer div. so it is over lapping anchor tags.

part of code `<div class="col-lg-12 col-md-8 col-sm-6 col-xs-4" id="disclaimer">`

[Working example](http://jsfiddle.net/93b1x26a/4/)

And your HTML is not in good format. syntax for break is `<br />` and you didn't close `p` tag in disclaimer properly.